# RichTextBox Void Colour

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I've created a log using **richtextbox1** and I want certain lines colored when asked on a void. Can you help me?

```
private void WriteLog(string textLog, Color corLog)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "] " + textoLog + Environment.NewLine;
    richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = cor; // THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

The color thing is not working. I want something that I could request any color on void, like:

```
WriteLog("Message",Color.Blue)
```

or

```
WriteLog("Message",Color.Red)
```

Comment: "on a void" what does this mean?

Comment: For future reference: please define "does not work". We can't see your system. Is there a compiler error, a runtime error, did something happen which you did not expect (or not happen what you did expect)? Please provide details of the problem.

Comment: @Thomas "cor" is an short term for "color"

Comment: Which is not defined, is it?

Comment: The line which **set the color** wasnt setting the color, but @Alex K already fixed. Thanks everyone

Comment: "on a method" still does not make sense (nor does replacing "on a void" with "method"). Please use standard terms of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the colour *then* set the text (better via `.AppendText()` rather than `+=`)

```
private void WriteLog(string textLog, Color corLog)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = corLog;
    richTextBox1.AppendText("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "] " + textLog + Environment.NewLine);
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Comment: 'better' is putting it mildly. It is indeed __imperative__ to use `AppendText` etc, ie __not__ to manipulate the `Text` property directly  if you want formatting to work!